# Is the relative speed of the UIActivityIndicatorView accessible?

Tags: objective-c, calayer, cabasicanimation

Want to create a loading view that matches the speed of the UIActivityIndicatorView depending on the network type.

Is it accessible via the SDK or at the very least disclosed?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How fast it spins? Short answer is no :(

Answer (score 0):

Not with a simple property or something like that. You do have a few options though:

1. Create it yourself. The images are available when you use [iOS Artwork Extractor](https://github.com/0xced/iOS-Artwork-Extractor), so you could give it the same look. Perhaps a little tedious. Maybe you could even subclass it.
2. Do some hackery with the current `startAnimating` and `stopAnimating` methods. Basically start and stop it for a period of time using a timer. This may not look great though as `NSTimer` doesn't always give you the precision you'd want in this case.
3. Since `UIActivityIndicatorView` inherits from `UIView`, you can access its `layer` property. This is a [`CALayer`](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/GraphicsImaging/Reference/CALayer_class/Introduction/Introduction.html#//apple_ref/doc/c_ref/CALayer), which has instance methods like `animationKeys` and `animationForKey`. This is probably the best way to go about it, though it's not very future-proof since you're modifying the internals which can always change.

Comment: Maybe the question wasn't clear enough. I'm interested in getting the speed that the UIActivityIndicatorView has while spinning. Would assume it's a constant, though obtaining it at runtime is also acceptable as long as it's not using any private API.

Comment: Oh wow, I totally misread that. Unfortunately, the network activity indicator is not available (not even a reference to it) with public APIs.